# ConnectFour Java Game Issues

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am a 9th grade student in Mr. Hill's coding class! Recently, he has asked us to create a Connect Four game which involves two players, prevents cheating (so player 1 can't keep placing pieces in one turn etc..) and will function like a real connect four game! I have started working on the code, however, Mr. Hill had a baby recently, and has been out of school the past week. Our substitute teacher doesn't know anything about coding, and I have already asked my friends, but I haven't been helped. Anyways, the requirements involve using a two dimensional array, and having the game "pieces" fall to the next available position when dropped down a column. The game needs to be 6 rows by 7 columns, have a reset button that clears the game, and has a 'player wins' counter. I have done my best in creating the board and checking for wins, but I'm not sure what's wrong. I tried to make a two dimensional game board of buttons, where the buttons will turn into a picture of a red or black piece when clicked. I apologize due to the fact that I am an amateur programmer, and so amateur mistakes will be made. I'm completely stuck, and not even sure this is correct. I would appreciate *any and all* help! Thank you so much and have a good day!

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class ConnectFourGame
{
  JFrame frame;
  JPanel panel;
  final int rowButtons = 6;
  final int columnButtons = 7;
  int row, column, rowSelected,columnSelected = 0;
  int playerTurn = 0;
  boolean win = false;
  JButton[][]board = new JButton[6][7];
  int[][] grid = new int [6][7];
  GridLayout gameBoard = new GridLayout (6,7);

  final ImageIcon red = new ImageIcon("red.png");
  final ImageIcon black = new ImageIcon("black.png");
  final ImageIcon blank = new ImageIcon("white.png");

  private JButton reset;
  private JLabel playerWins;

  //JLabelcheck


public ConnectFourGame()
{
  frame = new JFrame ("Connect Four Game");
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  panel = new JPanel();
  panel.setLayout(gameBoard);
  for (row = 6; row >= 0; row--)
  {
    for (column = 7; column >= 0; column--)
  {
    board[6][7] =new JButton();
    board[6][7].addActionListener(new boardListener());
    panel.add(board[6][7]); 
  }
}
frame.setContentPane(panel);
frame.setSize(700,600); //1400,1200
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.pack();
//frame.setResizable(false);
//frame.setLocation(807,170);

/*reset = new JButton("Reset Game");
reset.setBounds(1200,1000,100,170);
reset.addActionListener(this);
frame.add(reset);*/

/*playerWins = new JLabel("Player Wins");
playerWins.setBounds(70,900,100,370);
frame.add(playerWins);*/

/*board[row][column] = new JButton();
board[row][column].addActionListener(new boardListener());*/
}   
class boardListener implements ActionListener
{
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
  {
    //String (eventButton) = event.getActionCommand();
    if (win = false)
    {
     if(playerTurn % 2 == 0)
    {
     board[rowSelected][columnSelected].setIcon((red));
    }
     if(playerTurn % 2 == 1)
    {
     board[rowSelected][columnSelected].setIcon((black));
    }
    //if (JLabelCheck(columnSelected) == true)
    {
    checkWin();
    playerTurn = playerTurn + 1;
   }
  }
 }  
}
public boolean checkWin()
{
 for (int row = 0; row<6; row++)
 {
  for (int column = 0; column < 4; column++)
  {
   if(grid[column][row] != 0 && grid [column][row] == grid[column+1][row] && grid [column][row] == grid[column+2][row] && grid [column][row] == grid[column+3][row]);
 {
   win = true;
  }
 }
}
for(int row = 0; row<3; row++)
{
 for (int column=0; column<7; column++)
 {
if(grid[column][row] !=0 && grid [column][row] == grid[column][row+1] && grid [column][row]== grid[column][row+2] && grid [column][row] == grid[column][row+3]);
     {
       win = true;
      }
     }
    }
    for(int row = 0; row<3; row++)
    {
     for (int column=0; column<4; column++)
     {
    if(grid[column][row] !=0 && grid [column][row] == grid[column][row+1] && grid [column][row]== grid[column][row+2] && grid [column][row] == grid[column][row+3]);
     {
      win = true;
      }
     }
    }
    for(int row = 3; row<6; row++)
    {
     for (int column=0; column<4; column++)
     {
    if(grid[column][row] !=0 && grid [column][row] == grid[column+1][row-1] && grid [column][row]== grid[column+2][row-2] && grid [column][row] == grid[column+3][row-3]);
    {
      win = true;
      }
     }
    }
    return win;
    }

public static void main(String args[])
{
 javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
{
 public void run()
{
 JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
 new ConnectFourGame();
 {
 }
}
}
);
}
}
```

Comment: What is your issue, can you be more specific (also note that most readers do not care about your teacher life, so maybe you should cleanup this question?)

Comment: You have a problem with the arrays in your instance variables. Keep in mind that indices are zero-based, meaning counting starts at 0 rather than 1. When you try to assign a value to something such as `board[6][7]`, this throws an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, as the highest valid indices would be `board[5][6]`.

Comment: Spend a fair amount of time while you're in high school studying English composition.  That will help you write better organized code and better Stack Overflow questions.

Answer (score 2):

I try to give you some starting points to work on.

1. As @Bethany Louise mentioned, accessing an Array with an index equal to its length results in an IndexOutOfBoundsException. The highest accessible index is therefore length-1. The first index of an array is 0.
2. One advice, make use of final int rowButtons = 6; and final int columnButtons = 7; for initialization and inside every for loop, that can use the values. You have to change the code in multiple lines, if you want to change the number of rows for example. As code grows, it is easy to forget one value.
3. You need to use the row and column and please note 1..

   ```
   for (row = 6; row >= 0; row--)
   {
     for (column = 7; column >= 0; column--)
     {
       board[6][7] =new JButton();
       board[6][7].addActionListener(new boardListener());
       panel.add(board[6][7]); 
     }
   }
   ```
4. It may work, but ask yourself it is necassary to check the whole grid within checkWin() method. Is it not sufficient to check the surrounding of the last piece that was set? (Keep the Array bounds in mind)
5. board[rowSelected][columnSelected].setIcon. I don't see where rowSelected and columnSelected values are set in the code. If it is not set, try to figure out how you can get those values. (Hint, the button's action handler is called, so the button knows that it was called, but he needs to remember its position.)

Hope it helps.